# How does header and footer printing work in Puppeter's page.pdf API?

Tags: puppeteer

I've noticed a few inconsistencies when trying to use the `headerTemplate` and `footerTemplate` options with `page.pdf`:

- The DPI for headers and footers seems to be lower (72 vs 96 for the main body, I think). So if I'm trying to match the margins, I have to scale by that.
- Styles are not shared with the main body so I have to include them in the template.
- If I try to use a locally stored font, it works on the main body but not in the header/footer even if I include the same CSS in the header/footer template.

I suspect that this happens because headers and footers are treated as separate documents and converted to image/pdf separately (https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/printing/resources/print_header_footer_template_page.html also implies something like that). Can someone familiar with the implementation explain how it actually works? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51460641/364131) and codesearch, I think I found most of the answers I was looking for.

The printing implementation is in [PrintPageInternal](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/printing/renderer/print_render_frame_helper.cc?type=cs&g=0&l=1967). It uses two separate `WebFrame`s — one to render the content, and one to render the header and footer. The rendering for the header and footer is done by creating a [special frame](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/printing/renderer/print_render_frame_helper.cc?type=cs&g=0&l=618), writing the contents of [print_header_and_footer_template_page.html](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/printing/resources/print_header_footer_template_page.html) to this frame, calling the `setup` function with the options provided and then printing to a shared canvas. After this, the rest of the contents of the page are printed on the same canvas within the bounds defined by the margins.

Headers and footers are scaled by a [fudge_factor](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/printing/renderer/print_render_frame_helper.cc?type=cs&g=0&l=2027) which isn't applied to the rest of the content. There might be something funny going on here with the DPIs (which might explain the fudge_factor of `1.33333333f` which is equal to `96/72`).

I'm guessing this special frame is what prevents the header and footer from sharing the same resources (styles, fonts etc.) as the contents of the page. It probably isn't setup to load (and wait for) any additional resources requested by the header and footer templates, which is why the requested fonts don't load.

Comment: It'd be nice if we could replace that HTML file at run time.

Comment: These different DPIs are really crazy. I tried only for a test to `style="transform: scale(0.75);transform-origin: left;` (`72/96=0.75`) and it really match. After this scaling my border-widths are now same (header vs content). But with margins, etc are still problem.
It's really unbelievable this DPI sh*t: you set `margin` object for a page and then use same values of margins in inline-styles in header/footerTemplate and IT DOES NOT FIT (cause this DPI thing). And I do not know how to deal with that, coz simple multiplying or dividing with `96/72` factor is not working for me properly.

Comment: @MatějKříž I use `calc(0.75 * 1cm)` for all properties, works also for the margin.

Answer (score 23):

### Short Answer:

Puppeteer controls Chrome or Chromium over the [DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

Chromium uses [Skia](https://skia.org/) for PDF generation.

Skia handles the header, set of objects, and footer separately.

---

### Detailed Answer:

From the [Puppeteer Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions):

> #### page.pdf(options)
>
> - `options` <[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)> Options object which might have the following properties:
>
>   - `headerTemplate` <[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)> HTML template for the print header. Should be valid HTML markup with following classes used to inject printing values into them:
>
>     - `date` formatted print date
>     - `title` document title
>     - `url` document location
>     - `pageNumber` current page number
>     - `totalPages` total pages in the document
>   - `footerTemplate` <[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)> HTML template for the print footer. Should use the same format as the `headerTemplate`.
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<[Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer)>> Promise which resolves with PDF buffer.
>
> > **NOTE** Generating a pdf is currently only supported in Chrome headless.
>
> ---
>
> > **NOTE** `headerTemplate` and `footerTemplate` markup have the following limitations:
> >
> > 1. Script tags inside templates are not evaluated.
> > 2. Page styles are not visible inside templates.

---

We can learn from the the [Puppeteer source code for `page.pdf()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/Page.js#L866) that:

- The Chrome DevTools Protocol method `Page.printToPDF` (along with the `headerTemplate` and `footerTemplate` parameters) are sent to to `page._client`.
- `page._client` is an instance of `page.target().createCDPSession()` (a Chrome DevTools Protocol session).

---

From the [Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-printToPDF), we can see that `Page.printToPDF` contains the parameters `headerTemplate` and `footerTemplate`:

> #### Page.printToPDF
>
> Print page as PDF.
>
> PARAMETERS
>
> - `headerTemplate` **string** (optional)
>
>   - HTML template for the print header. Should be valid HTML markup with following classes used to inject printing values into them:
>
>     - `date`: formatted print date
>     - `title`: document title
>     - `url`: document location
>     - `pageNumber`: current page number
>     - `totalPages`: total pages in the document
>   - For example, `<span class=title></span>` would generate span containing the title.
> - `footerTemplate` **string** (optional)
>
>   - HTML template for the print footer. Should use the same format as the `headerTemplate`.
>
> RETURN OBJECT
>
> - `data` **string**
>
>   - Base64-encoded pdf data.

---

The [Chromium source code for `Page.printToPDF`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/out/Debug/gen/headless/public/devtools_js/page.js?q=printToPDF&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=1914) shows us that:

- The `Page.printToPDF` parameters are passed to the [`sendDevToolsMessage`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/lib/browser/devtools_api/devtools_connection.js?q=sendDevToolsMessage&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=148) function, which issues a DevTools protocol command and returns a promise for the results.

---

After further digging, we can see that Chromium has a concrete [implementation of a class called `SkDocument`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/skia/src/pdf/SkPDFDocument.h?type=cs&q=Concrete%20implementation%20of%20SkDocument&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=54) that creates PDF files.

[`SkDocument`](https://skia.org/user/sample/pdf) comes from the [Skia Graphics Library](https://skia.org/), which [Chromium uses for PDF generation](https://skia.org/dev/chrome).

The [Skia PDF Theory of Operation](https://skia.org/dev/design/pdftheory), in the [PDF Objects and Document Structure](https://skia.org/dev/design/pdftheory#PDF_Objects_and_Document_Structure) section, states that:

> **Background**: The PDF file format has **a header**, a **set of objects** and then **a footer** that contains a table of contents for all of the objects in the document (the cross-reference table). The table of contents lists the specific byte position for each object. The objects may have references to other objects and the ASCII size of those references is dependent on the object number assigned to the referenced object; therefore we can’t calculate the table of contents until the size of objects is known, which requires assignment of object numbers. The document uses `SkWStream::bytesWritten()` to query the offsets of each object and build the cross-reference table.

The document explains further down:

> The PDF backend requires all indirect objects used in a PDF to be added to the `SkPDFObjNumMap` of the `SkPDFDocument`. The catalog is responsible for assigning object numbers and generating the table of contents required at the end of PDF files. In some sense, generating a PDF is a three step process. In the first step all the objects and references among them are created (mostly done by `SkPDFDevice`). In the second step, `SkPDFObjNumMap` assigns and remembers object numbers. Finally, in the third step, the **header is printed**, **each object is printed**, and then the **table of contents and trailer are printed**. `SkPDFDocument` takes care of collecting all the objects from the various `SkPDFDevice` instances, adding them to an `SkPDFObjNumMap`, iterating through the objects once to set their file positions, and iterating again to generate the final PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I do a lot of research on this issue and finally, I implement a small library to handle this issue by a small hack:

[image]

I create two PDF files. The first one is the HTML content without header and footer. And the second one is the header and footer repeated based upon original content PDF pages' number, then merges them together.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/PejmanNik/puppeteer-report